# Wifi problem on hp 355 g2 laptop

Tags: wireless, laptop, hp, 15.10

I have a problem with my wifi connection. I have a HP 355 G2 and WiFi doesn't work on 14.04, 14.10 or 15.04 and 15.10. I can fix this like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: This does not work on wily because I have to fix the PPA for kernel 4.2. I will do it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue in my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi). It now works for all supported Ubuntu versions.